Ansible doesn't see docker containers
When I run this command ansible all -m ping.
Ansible is giving me this
client-1 | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: connect to host 172.17.0.2 port 22: Connection refused",
    "unreachable": true
}
client-2 | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: connect to host 172.17.0.3 port 22: Connection refused",
    "unreachable": true
}

My /etc/ansible/hosts file:
client-1 ansible_host=172.17.0.2 ansible_user=root ansible_password=ptest
client-2 ansible_host=172.17.0.3 ansible_user=utest ansible_password=ptest

and /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg file
[default]
inventory = /etc/ansible/hosts
host_key_checking = false

I've tried to install python3-pip in both containers.
I've tried to put them in the same network with docker network command.
But I still cannot ping those containers with Ansible.

hi. ssh: connect to host 172.17.0.3 port 22: Connection refused so is ssh reachable there? Why is ansible to blame, and not the containers? Is ssh server running inside containers? What does it mean "doesn't see"? What containers? Where are containers runnning? Is container reachable on 172.17.0.2? What container?

@KamilCuk. Both containers are using ubuntu, And when you ask me "Is ssh server running inside containers?" does this mean that ssh server need to work in both containers? Containers running on my laptop. And yeah, i forget to say this, but if i use ping command, well, containers are being pinged.

You probably want to use the community.docker.docker connection to connect to a container: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/docker/docker_connection.html

that ssh server need to work in both containers? Yes. Did you run and configure sshd in both containers?

A container normally only runs a single process, and that process isn't usually an ssh daemon.  You'd normally set up a reproducible image using a Dockerfile and just run it; you don't need to manage it with tools like Ansible the way you would a full VM.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

My best bet is that your ansible user does not have access to the docker socket. If I am right, you have two option: either give access to the socket, or use the become_user (sudo) and switch to a user who has.

There is no need to have an SSH daemon in containers, because Ansible can us a plugin for Docker connections (similar to docker exec). If you are using ansible community then this docker connection plugin is included. If not then ansible-galaxy collection install community.docker
Now your inventory hosts file, write it with the container names as "hosts", and specify their ansible_connection:
[containers]
client-1
client-2
[containers:vars]
ansible_connection=community.docker.docker

Then try ansible containers -m ping.
Note: You should sudo, be root, or in the docker group to connect.
